# Problems with Weight Paint

Tags: weight-painting

I'm new and don't know my way around yet, but I'm having a little problem when I try to use *Weight Paint*.

When I try to use *Weight Paint*, it paints the back but not the front, but this only affects the right arm and the right leg and even if I set the weight to 0, it still paints as if it has weight 1.

If there is a solution to this problem I would be very grateful.

[image: Applied the paint with just one click for a clear example]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to disable the *Auto Normalize* option:

[image]

Comment: Got it working, I just need to recalculate the faces.

Comment: oh ok then  ;)  ................